# Manually building binary packages from source that are found on Launchpad

Tags: package-management, deb, launchpad, openssh

I'm trying to build the latest source of openSSH (https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable). If I use checkinstall, I end up with a single .deb that installs *everything*, whereas Ubuntu/launchpad are somehow dividing the installation up into several binary packages.

From openssh they're building these debs (see https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.1):

- openssh-client
- openssh-client-udeb
- openssh-server
- openssh-server-udeb
- openssh-sftp-server
- ssh-askpass-gnome
- ssh-krb5 openssh-client-dbgsym
- openssh-client-ssh1-dbgsym
- openssh-client-udeb-dbgsym
- openssh-server-dbgsym
- openssh-sftp-server-dbgsym
- ssh
- ssh-askpass-gnome-dbgsym

I've found the build log (https://launchpadlibrarian.net/278424435/buildlog_ubuntu-xenial-amd64.openssh_1%3A7.2p2-4ubuntu2.1_BUILDING.txt.gz) where I can suss out what ./configure was used.

Essentially, how can I replay what was done on Launchpad to build openSSH, but with an updated source? It's a long story, but I have to be able to build these binary packages from the latest openSSH codebase, and I'm trying to do this in a way that's still compatible with Launchpad and apt.